# What are the recommended steps to take before selling an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, security, privacy

I "lost" my iPhone at work, could not find it anywhere. I reported it lost, and got another through the insurance. A month later, I found it hiding in a file in one my desk drawers. The phone is just less than a year old, in near new condition, and it seems a waste to discard it. What has to be done to be able to sell it to someone who needs a working phone?

Comment: Please change the title of your post because the current one is not related to the question you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of privacy - unlink your AppleID account and just go to `Settings > General > Reset`. Clean everything (Reset All Settings & Erease All Content and Settings) and you're ready to sell / give your phone.

[image]